# want to store multiple values in a string and Send it in a json format

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to receive values in a single variable which is coming from some method and then convert all these values in Json format for sending.
Here i am talking about studentName,studentEmail,studentPhoneNumber and studentPassw which is coming from method 'getSysFileJsonSendToServer' called somewhere now inside this method i want to store all these variable to store in a single varible "concat" and change it in json format for sending .
Below is my code where i am trying

```
  public async static Task<string> getSysFileJsonSendToServer(string studentName, string studentEmail, string studentPhoneNumber, string studentPassw)
            {
                DateTime dateTimeCurrent = await WebServiceManager.GetDateFromServer();
                DateTime localTime = dateTimeCurrent.ToLocalTime();
                string localDateTimeString = Utility.getFormatedDate(localTime);
                string finalJsonObjectToServer = string.Empty;
                try
                {

                    Stream serverStream = null;
                    string readData = string.Empty;
                    string msg = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
                    string concat= {"name":"studentName","phone":"studentPhoneNumber","mail_id":"studentEmail","studentPassw":"hkfgd","profile":"God","status":"1","created_at":"localDateTimeString"}
}
```

Comment: You should just use [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree with @DrewKennedy.  You should find a JSON library to use for creating and parsing JSON in your code.

Comment: how could you show any example i am new to these thing..

Comment: Yeah I'll whip something quick for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a JSON library to accomplish what you're trying to do - they save you a lot of time in coding, and provide consistency in serialization and deserialization. My recommendation is [Newtsonsoft Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Here's a quick example for you:

```
class Student {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   //more properties
}

...

var student = new Student {
    Name = "My Name",
    Phone = "555-453-6547"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);//now in json format

//now a Student object
Student deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
```

`Newtonsoft` also [fully supports async](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObjectAsync__1_1.htm) if you need to go that route.

To use `Newtonsoft`, you can go to your nuget package manager:

> Tools → Nuget Package Manager → Manage Nuget Packages for Solution..

Then search for `Newtsonsoft` and install. After completion, make sure you add the DLL reference in your list of references, then add a using statement:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```